Read-only DB find entity queries return null when fired by concurrent threads using java Spring framework
I have a code along the following lines:

// An Issue is a ticket describing a requirement, like a Jira issue or a github issue.
Stream<Issue> issueStream = getIssueStreamFromDB();
Iterator<Issue> issues = issueStream.iterator();

while(issues.hasNext()){
   ParallelBatch<FeatureMinerBean> batch = new ParallelBatch(batchSize);
   while(!batch.isFull && issues.hasNext()){
        Issue issue = issues.next();
        batch.add(new FeatureMinerBean(issue, restOfArguments));
   }
   
    // execute measurements in parallel to issues in batch
    batch.parallelStream().forEach(b -> doMeasurements(b));

   // rest of code ...
}

As you can imagine from the code above, I want to process a stream of issues I'm getting from a Postgres DB. The fetching of issues is done by the main thread, who collects batches of them to be processed by the worker threads provided by the java Stream api.
The doMeasurements() internally invokes a set of methods, each one with the responsibility to perfom a measuring of a metric. In order to complete such a task, some methods need to perform queries to the DB.
The problem is the following. If the measurements are performed by the main thread (namely, the stream returned by the batch is a sequential one) everything works. Conversely, if I switch to a parallel stream as the one showed in the code sample above, all queries to the db performed by the worker threads return either null values (i.e. find() methods) or zeros (i.e. count() methods).
I would like to resort to a parallel stream because I expect the number of issues to be high and the measuring of the metrics can be quite expensive because of their numbers and complexity.
Is this intendend behaviour? Am I missing some step to perfom in order to be able to access the db from multiple threads?
I'm using Spring+Hibernate stack to interact with the persistence layer through JPA.
All of the above code and the doMeasurements() method are annotated with @Transactional.
I'm using java version 17 so I should not be using the stream api version coming from java 8.
EDIT:
I've found the cause of the behaviour: DB data population and workers spawning happen in same transaction. Probably, workers thread queries see an empty DB because the data saving performed when populating the DB have not been committed yet.
I've divided the code in different transactions, and the failure changed appareance. Now, when workers try to get streams from DB, the following exception is raised:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState

Maybe JpaRepository proxies generated by Spring are not thread safe?

Generally speaking, it is problematic for JavaEE applications to start their own threads.  Spring repositories in particular are thread safe with respect to container managed threads, but I am not aware of them being thread-safe with respect to unmanaged threads, such as your parallel stream is probably using.

@JohnBollinger Thank you for your contribution. My final objective is to parallelize the calling of the measurement methods specified in the doMeasurements() method. Using the parallel stream facilities is not an hard requirement of mine. Can you kindly give me some pointers to more information in order to learn more about these container managed threads you speak of so that I can check if I can leverage them to fulfill my task?

At one point, you could not gain access to (additional) container-managed threads at all, but there are ways in more recent versions of Java EE.  Here's a starting point: Java EE specification and multi threading.

But be aware that although code running in a Java EE container should avoid creating unmanaged threads, complying with that might not be sufficient for your purposes. My previous comments about container-managed threads were more about the fact that Java EE containers are generally multithreaded, and Spring doesn't have a problem with that.  Generally speaking, it is safest to use injected or looked-up resources only in the thread in which the injection or lookup was performed.

You could consider pushing your computation (more) into the DB, as a single native query or stored procedure if possible.  That tends to be more performant than doing Java-side computations involving multiple queries.

After doing some research, I think that my application is not a JavaEE one. I'm am using the Sping framework stack up to the @Service components layer. There are  no REST controllers as well as no dependency to a web server such as Tomcat. I'm convincing myself about this since I'm having many configuration issues setting up managed threads (i.e. JNDI properties not set). Am I missing something?

Could it be that, since transaction should be isolated from each other, transactions started from worker threads cannot see in their queires data saved in transaction started from the main thread? Maybe data storing has not been committed before worker threads try to query it?
